# How to run one script remotely on several hosts

Tags: bash, terminal, parallel-processing, console, gnu-parallel

I have some hosts in my ~/.ssh/config
Some of them are in ./my.nodes file

I want to run script (./myscript.sh) on hosts which are listed in my.nodes.

I can do this using next command:

```
parallel --sshloginfile ./my.nodes --bf ./myscript.sh ::: ./myscript.sh ./myscript.sh
```

This command will run script only 2 nodes. If I want to run it on N nodes, I should repeat 'myscript.sh' at the end of this command N times.

Is it possible to run script on all nodes from file ./my.nodes without repeating 'myscript.sh' at the end of command?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

```
parallel --nonall --sshloginfile ./my.nodes --bf ./myscript.sh ./myscript.sh
```

Please notice that `--nonall` is a bit misleading... it means `--onall` *with no arguments*.